# Unreliable serial communication with pl2303

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, pthreads, reliability

Connected two PL2303 devices TX-> RX, RX->TX and connected to my Linux machine

I wrote an C application which will perform the following operation:

1. Port1 -> “sends a known data of 256 bytes” -> Port2
2. Port2 reads the data and verifies that it actually received the same data which Port1 transmitted
3. Port2 -> “sends a known data of 256 bytes different than which port1 sent” -> Port1
4. Port1 reads the data and verifies that it actually received the same data which Port2 transmitted

Used two threads one for each port

In the final step, if we don’t have ‘sleep + tcflush’ before read, buffer read by Port1 will have some of the data it transmitted to Port2 in the first step.

Here is the snippet of my code.

```
// Even port number execution part
        if (!(port_num % 2)) {
            // Write to a given port
            sem_wait(&semaphore[port_num]); // Wait until read is called for odd port
            bytes_written = write(fd, write_buffer_even, size_even);
            if (bytes_written == -1 || bytes_written != size_even) {
                fprintf(fp, "%s: Failed to write buffer\n", port_name);
                thread_params->retval = -errno;
                goto exit;
            }
            // For some reason, I need to add a delay before flushing.
            // The cause of this problem lies in using a USB serial port.
            // If you use a regular serial port, you will not have this problem.
            usleep(300000L); // Required to make flush work
            tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

            // Read from a given port
            sem_post(&semaphore[port_num + 1]);
            bytes_read = read(fd, read_buffer, size_even);
            if (bytes_read == -1) {
                fprintf(fp, "%s: Failed to read buffer\n", port_name);
                thread_params->retval = -errno;
                goto exit;
            }
            // Check for read bytes, complete & valid or not
            if (size_odd != bytes_read) {
                fprintf(fp, "%s: Read size mismatch - Expected %d bytes,"
                        "Read %zd bytes\n", port_name, size_odd, bytes_read);
                thread_params->retval = -ECOMM;
                thread_params->fail_count++;
            } else {
                if(strncmp(write_buffer_odd, read_buffer, size_odd)) {
                    fprintf(fp, "%s: Read data mismatch - Expected \"%s\""
                            "Read \"%s\"", port_name, write_buffer_odd,
                            read_buffer);
                    thread_params->retval = -ECOMM;
                    thread_params->fail_count++;
                } else {
                    thread_params->success_count++;
                }
            }
        // Odd port number execution part
        } else {
            // For some reason, I need to add a delay before flushing.
            // The cause of this problem lies in using a USB serial port.
            // If you use a regular serial port, you will not have this problem.
            usleep(300000L); // Required to make flush work
            tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

            // Read from a given port
            sem_post(&semaphore[port_num - 1]);
            bytes_read = read(fd, read_buffer, size_odd);
            if (bytes_read == -1) {
                fprintf(fp, "%s: Failed to read buffer\n", port_name);
                thread_params->retval = -errno;
                goto exit;
            }
            // Check for read bytes, complete & valid or not
            if (size_even != bytes_read) {
                fprintf(fp, "%s: Read size mismatch - Expected %d bytes,"
                        "Read %zd bytes\n", port_name, size_even, bytes_read);
                thread_params->retval = -ECOMM;
                thread_params->fail_count++;
            } else {
                if(strncmp(write_buffer_even, read_buffer, size_even)) {
                    fprintf(fp, "%s: Read data mismatch - Expected \"%s\""
                            "Read \"%s\"", port_name, write_buffer_even,
                            read_buffer);
                    thread_params->retval = -ECOMM;
                    thread_params->fail_count++;
                } else {
                    thread_params->success_count++;
                }
            }

            // Write to a given port
            sem_wait(&semaphore[port_num]); // Wait until read is called for read port
            bytes_written = write(fd, write_buffer_odd, size_odd);
            if (bytes_written == -1 || bytes_written != size_odd) {
                fprintf(fp, "%s: Failed to write buffer\n", port_name);
                thread_params->retval = -errno;
                goto exit;
            }
        }
```

I changed to other USB to serial devices like cp2104, cp2108 and the behavior is still same. What is the mistake I am making it, I dont want to have sleep in my application, as it is affecting my performance.

Added termios settings:

```
// Open the port
    sprintf(port_name, "/dev/ttyUSB%d", port_num);
    fd = open(port_name, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(fp, "%s: Failed to open %s  port with status:%d\n",
                __func__, port_name, -errno);
        thread_params->retval = -errno;
        goto exit;
    }

    // Set configuration for serial port
    tcgetattr(fd, &config);
    config.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ECHOE | ECHOK | ECHONL
            | ECHOCTL | ECHOPRT | ECHOKE);
    cfsetispeed(&config, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&config, B9600);
    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &config);
```

Comment: You're not handling reads correctly: unless you have configured the serial terminal in a certain way (and you don't bother to show that termios initialization), there is no guarantee that you will get the entire block in just one syscall. *"I dont want to have sleep in my application"* -- Why are you using **tcflush()**, that's typically nonsensical outside an initialization or error recovery sequence? Shouldn't you be using **tcdrain()** instead?

Comment: Even if I use tcdrain, I still need to use sleep and tcflush to get reliable communication.. added termios information

Comment: *"Even if I use tcdrain, I still need to use sleep and tcflush to get reliable communication."* -- So explain why you think you need to use **tcflush()** at all.  Your termios code is incomplete.  You leave the selection of canonical versus raw mode completely up to chance.

Comment: I am not sure but after adding it is working as expected, so you mean tcflush is not required

Comment: Do you find any problem with termios settings. If we change to non canonical mode will it solve the problem

Comment: Also I have seen one more behavior ttyUSB0 and ttyUSB1 are connected. When I call write first on one tty and then read on the other tty I don't get data, but if I create a thread which is running read and waiting for data, then I call write from another thread then read returns data, is this an expected behavior for ttyUSB devices

Comment: *"Also I have seen one more behavior ..."* -- There's no code shown, so no analysis.  *"If we change to non canonical mode will it solve the problem"* -- That could correct one of your errors.   *"I am not sure but after adding it is working as expected"* -- That is just about the worst reason for using **sleep()** and **tcflush()**.  Have you even looked up the **man** pages to understand what those syscalls actually do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187294/discussion-between-md-jamal-and-sawdust).